# How to format a statement into strings and number with print()

Tags: python

I have program which print the following

```
Test1 234
This is okay 1234
Bet 23
```

How to format into the following using python?

```
Test1        234
This is okay 1234
Bet          23
```

Comment: What have you tried?  If you know the longest string is 20 characters, use `print("%-20s %d" % (str,num) )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ljust` ("left justify") method that strings have.  For example, `'hi'.ljust(5)` would be `'hi   '`.

Suppose your data was arranged like

```py
data = [('Test1', 234), ('This is okay', 1234), ('Bet', 23)]
```

You would first determine the maximum length:

```py
max_len = max(len(x[0]) for x in data)
```

Then

```py
for (msg, num) in data:
    print('{} {}'.format(msg.ljust(max_len), num))
```